# Can't resolve method with key value pair in splitter

Tags: java

Hi this should be simple but i am getting this error "Can't resolve method with key value pair in splitter"  , i am using below library , can you please help what i am missing here

//dependency:

```
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0-jre'
```

Can't see the function for withKeyValueSeparator as its giving error on that

//import

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter.*;

Map<String, String> map2=

                Splitter.on(';').trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=>") .split("params");
```

Comment: What are you splitting? What is the expected result? Without this information, we can't help you. We can only guess.

Comment: i was able to resolve using this import   "import io.cucumber.messages.internal.com.google.common.base.Splitter;" but this is not working with cucumber 7.0, for now i degraded back to 6.7 , will keep looking for options with cucumber 7.0

Comment: None of those details were clear. For example, Cucumber wasn't tagged or mentioned. I **strongly** suggest you update this question.

Comment: You are going to want to import _Splitter_ and _Splitter.*_.

Comment: @Reilas Really, just import Splitter.

Comment: @DavidConrad, wouldn't you also need _Splitter.*_ for the inner class?

Comment: @Reilas If you use it, sure, but it isn't used in the code OP posted in the question.

Comment: @DavidConrad, so just the _Splitter_ import.  Great!

Comment: @Reilas No. You do not need to import `Spitter.*` for the inner class. Why? Look at my code example. I am using it when calling `split()`. The inner class is a member of the outer class I can reference it (statically) by using the already imported outer class.

Comment: @hfontanez, what about _com.google.common.base.*_, wouldn't that be a better approach?

Comment: @Reilas ABSOLUTELY NOT!!! Importing using wildcards like that is IMO a huge code smell. Import what you are actively using, nothing else. Imagine a package with 1,000 classes, but you are only using one. Why import the other 999 if they will never be used?

Comment: @Reilas when you import unused resources using wildcard, assume that along with that, you will be importing unused dependencies, which may result is longer build times since you have to pull more and more resources, and also you'll be building larger artifacts. Both of those things are bad. Bigger artifacts take longer to download, and we all hate when downloads take a long time. Don't we?

Answer (score 2):

Using the version in the original question:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>27.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

I created a simple program to demonstrate how to use `Splitter` class to properly create a `Map` using the original arguments.

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

public class SplitterDemo {
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String inputStr = "key1 => value1; key2 => value2; key3 => value3";
        Map<String, String> myMap = Splitter.on(";").trimResults().withKeyValueSeparator("=>").split(inputStr); 
        myMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

The result of the program is as expected

```
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
```

I don't know what Cucumber has to do with anything in this context; since details were lacking on the question to say the least. But this works just fine. And, if the splitting needs to occur within a Cucumber test, it should work just the same.

And if I change my input string to be something like this

```
"key1 => value1; key2 => value2; key3 => value3; foo = bar, bar=>baz"
```

the last entry set should be `foo = bar, bar=baz` since everything to the left of the delimiter is `foo = bar, bar` and everything to the right is simply `baz`. If an entry separator is anything other than a semicolon, the execution will result in an exception thrown.

In my opinion, it is this straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

i was able to resolve using this import
import io.cucumber.messages.internal.com.google.common.base.Splitter

but this is not working with cucumber 7.0 only with 6.7  will keep looking for options with cucumber 7.0

Comment: Even though this seemed to work, it might not be a good answer for this problem. Since your original question lacks details, it is anyone's guess. As I suggested in your question, update the question to include all relevant details: What you are trying to do, what is the expected result, etc. All we have is the error you got and the version of the guava library you are using. This is OK, but not close to be enough to be considered "a good question." That's most likely why someone already voted to close your question (and why your question is being downvoted).

Comment: Come to think of it, you didn't fix anything. All you did was to change the `Splitter` class and now you have a new issue. It would've been a "valid" fix if you had kept `com.google.common.base.Splitter` and downgrading Cucumber would've worked somehow. That's not what you did. I am sure the original class would work regardless of Cucumber version if you really fix the root cause of the original problem.